# Axapta: Filtering with wildcard in a 3000 char text field returns an SQL error

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I need a 3000 char string field that could be filtered by. It works fine when I don't use wildcards, but adding a wildcard causes an SQL error. I tried lowering the size to 1000 and the error went away, so I'm assuming that the problem is in field size.

Is this something that can be fixed with configuration? I don't know what the actual error is, it just says "SQL database has issued an error". I'm working on Ax 2009.

Comment: We cannot help you without exact error. Check SQL log or trace with SQL profiler.

Comment: Maybe the error is also logged in Adminstration\Periode\Database\SQL statement trace

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem, in my case I also got the info message: [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Invalid precision value. Googling that message didn't bring any helpful results. Some more trial and error revealed that the limit seems to be a string length of 2000 characters.

Comment: This might be related http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971051